# Choosing a score for factor analysis

Tags: feature-selection, factor-analysis

I want to perform factor analysis to reduce the number of variables in my dataset (the variables are very redundant). One of the parameters I need to supply to the R code is the number of factors to retain. In order to choose this number, I intend to try several numbers and evaluate the best number on a training set. I found several scores pertaining to factor analysis: regression, Bartlett, and Anderson-Rubin. Which score shall I choose to evaluate my factor number? In which situation is any of these scores more 'appropriate'?

Comment: http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/spssstat/v20r0m0/topic/com.ibm.spss.statistics.help/idh_fact_sco.htm

Answer (score 1):

Instead of choosing the number of factors based on *any* score, I would choose the solution that makes sense in your context. Look at the factors and see if they will help you in any way. The goal of factor analysis is to find latent variables; which solution finds sensible latent variables?

Your first sentence is a bit worrying; it sounds like you may want principal component analysis instead.